# Divide csv file by column value

Tags: python, csv

I have over 200 files that I want to divide by the column clName value and keep the header in all files.I also want to save this files with the OriginalFileName-clName.txt

```
ID  Plate   Well      ctr        clID     clName
21    5      C03        1       50012       COL
21    5      C03        1       50012       COL
21    5      C03        1       50012       COL 
21    5      C04        1       50012       IA 
21    5      C04        1       50012       IA 
21    5      C05        1       50012       ABC 


import csv
from itertools import groupby

for key, rows in groupby(csv.reader(open("file.csv")),
                         lambda row: row[7]):
    with open("%s.txt" % key, "w") as output:
        for row in rows:
            output.write(",".join(row) + "\n")
```

The problem I have is the column won't always be called clName, it can be called clName, cll_n, c_Name. And sometimes this it will be column 7, other times column 5 or 9.

What I have know separates the file by the column value but does not keep the header and I have to check every file to find if its column 5, 7, 9,etc.

Is there a way for me to check the column names from a list of names and when one of the names is found split the file by that column value?

example data 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzv1SNKM1p4uell3UVlQb0U3ZGM/view?usp=sharing

Thank you

Comment: do you mean you want to add the last column header to the end of the file?  How would you identify if the correct name is in column 5, 7 or 9?

Comment: No. Just keep header in every file. And save the file with the column value and original file name,like originalfile-COL.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `csv.DictReader` and `csv.DictWriter` instead. Here is an outline that should point you in the right direction.

```
special_col = ['cll_n', 'clName']

with open('myfile.csv', 'r') as fh:
    rdr = csv.DictReader(fh)

    # now we need to figure out which column is used
    for c in special_col:
        if c in rdr.fieldnames:
            break  # found the column name
    else:
        raise IOError('No special column in file')

    # now execute your existing code, but group by the
    # column using lambda row: row[c] instead of row 7
    call_existing_code(rdr, c)


def call_existing_code(rdr, c):
    # set up an output file using csv.DictWriter; you can
    # replace the original column with the new column, and
    # control the order of fields

    with open('output.csv', 'w') as fh:
        wtr = csv.DictWriter(fh, fieldnames=['list', 'of', 'fields'])
        wtr.writeheader()

        for row in groupby(rdr, lambda r: r[c]):

            # [process the row as needed here]

            wtr.writerow(row)
```